# Merge Sort in C++: Unable to pass array in merge function - invalid conversion to 'int*'

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am trying write a merge sort function in C++, however I am getting an error on (in the MergeSort function):

```
    A = MergeSort (A, x);
    B = MergeSort (B, y);
    C = Merge(A,B,x,y);
```

as an invalid conversion from int to int*. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is my function code:

```
int MergeSort (int [], int);
int Merge (int [], int [], int, int);


int MergeSort (int arr[], int len) {
    int x = len/2;
    int y = len-x;
    int i,j;

    // initialize the arrays
    int * A = new int [x];
    int * B = new int [y];
    int * C = new int [len];

    // copy left and right arrays
    for (i=0, j=0; i<x; i++, j++) {
        A[i] = arr[j];
    }

    for (i=0; i<y; i++, j++) {
        B[i] = arr[j];
    }

    A = MergeSort (A, x);
    B = MergeSort (B, y);
    C = Merge(A,B,x,y);

    return C;
}

int Merge(int A[], int B[], int x, int y) {
    int i,j,k;
    i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;

    int * C = new int[x+y];

    while (i < x && j < y) {
        if (A[i] < B[j])
            C[k++] = A[i++];
        else
            C[k++] = B[j++];
    }

    if (i < x) //A is longer
        C[k++] = A[i++];
    if (j < y) //B is longer
        C[k++] = B[j++];

    return C;

}
```

And here is my main function:

```
int main() {

    //initialize array with some values
    int ar [8] = {7, 5, 9, 1, 4, 22, 11, 10};

    cout<<"array:";
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
        cout<<ar[i];
    cout<<endl;

    //run merge sort
    ar = MergeSort(ar,8);

    cout<<"merged array:";
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            cout<<arr[i];
        cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, `C` is declared as `int*` and returned as `int` rather than as `int*`. Of course, your program is full of memory leaks as you allocate memory in multiple places but never release it. You might want to have a look at `std::vector<int>` to represent your arrays.

Also, in the `main()` function you try to assign an `int` to an array: you can’t assign to buiLt-in arrays at all, you can only assign to individual elements. Using `std::vector<int>` would avoid this problem, too.